# Upload a profile picture with FOSUserBundke

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, fosuserbundle

My file isn't uploading on my pc, and there is no update on the database for profileFilePath...I don't know what is wrong. I hope you can help me !

my User.php.

```
<?php

namespace L3O1\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="l3o1_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="2048k")
     * @Assert\Image(mimeTypesMessage="Please upload a valid image.")
     */
    protected $profilePictureFile;

    // for temporary storage
    private $tempProfilePicturePath;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $profilePicturePath;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Sets the file used for profile picture uploads
     * 
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     * @return object
     */
    public function setProfilePictureFile(UploadedFile $file = null) {
        // set the value of the holder
        $this->profilePictureFile       =   $file;
         // check if we have an old image path
        if (isset($this->profilePicturePath)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->tempProfilePicturePath = $this->profilePicturePath;
            $this->profilePicturePath = null;
        } else {
            $this->profilePicturePath = 'initial';
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the file used for profile picture uploads
     * 
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getProfilePictureFile() {

        return $this->profilePictureFile;
    }

    /**
     * Set profilePicturePath
     *
     * @param string $profilePicturePath
     * @return User
     */
    public function setProfilePicturePath($profilePicturePath)
    {
        $this->profilePicturePath = $profilePicturePath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get profilePicturePath
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getProfilePicturePath()
    {
        return $this->profilePicturePath;
    }

    /**
     * Get the absolute path of the profilePicturePath
     */
    public function getProfilePictureAbsolutePath() {
        return null === $this->profilePicturePath
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->profilePicturePath;
    }

    /**
     * Get root directory for file uploads
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getUploadRootDir($type='profilePicture') {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir($type);
    }

    /**
     * Specifies where in the /web directory profile pic uploads are stored
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getUploadDir($type='profilePicture') {
        // the type param is to change these methods at a later date for more file uploads
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/user/profilepics';
    }

    /**
     * Get the web path for the user
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWebProfilePicturePath() {

        return '/'.$this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getProfilePicturePath(); 
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUploadProfilePicture() {
        if (null !== $this->getProfilePictureFile()) {
            // a file was uploaded
            // generate a unique filename
            $filename = $this->generateRandomProfilePictureFilename();
            $this->setProfilePicturePath($filename.'.'.$this->getProfilePictureFile()->guessExtension());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates a 32 char long random filename
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function generateRandomProfilePictureFilename() {
        $count                  =   0;
        do {
            $generator = new SecureRandom();
            $random = $generator->nextBytes(16);
            $randomString = bin2hex($random);
            $count++;
        }
        while(file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$randomString.'.'.$this->getProfilePictureFile()->guessExtension()) && $count < 50);

        return $randomString;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     * 
     * Upload the profile picture
     * 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function uploadProfilePicture() {
        // check there is a profile pic to upload
        if ($this->getProfilePictureFile() === null) {
            return;
        }
        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->getProfilePictureFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->getProfilePicturePath());

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->tempProfilePicturePath) && file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->tempProfilePicturePath)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->tempProfilePicturePath);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->tempProfilePicturePath = null;
        }
        $this->profilePictureFile = null;
    }

     /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeProfilePictureFile()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getProfilePictureAbsolutePath() && file_exists($this->getProfilePictureAbsolutePath())) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

My form type

```
<?php
namespace L3O1\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('profilePictureFile');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_profile';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'l3o1_user_profile';
    }
}
```

And my form in my edit_content.html.twig

```
     <form action="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="fos_user_profile_edit">

    <!-- left column -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>
        <img src="/ProjetSVN/web{{app.user.getWebProfilePicturePath}}" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">
        {{ form_row(form.profilePictureFile, {'label': 'Profile picture'}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.profilePictureFile, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control' }})}}
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save change" type="button">
            <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you update your question with the controller code

Comment: I did not change the FOSUser controller, should I ? I thought the upload is going though Doctrine.

Comment: ah you use events PostPersist you can check then if the event works using vardump or exits

Comment: Sorry for my late post ! I'm not sure what I should vardump ?

Comment: just var_dump('it goes inside'); exit; just to check if the postpersist is executed

Comment: If I do what you told me to do, I put it in my formType I get
string 'it goes inside' (length=14)

Comment: no what i want to know is if uploadProfilePicture is triggered so the vardump should go there not the formtype.

Comment: It seem that upload isn't trigered. Nothing show after I click on "upload".

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. It was because in my twig, i used `{{ form_widget(form.file) }}`instead of `{{ form_widget(form) }}` ! But I'm not sure to understand why. It seem that with FOSUB, when you update your profile you MUST put your password for verification. That why, I think it doesn't upload or update database.

Comment: You had your form_rest(form) in the twig? maybe the token was missing or the enctype also

Comment: I didn't use {{ form_rest(form) }} but {{ form_widget(form.profilePictureFile) }} because I always wanted to show the file input. I don't want the user to put his password in order to change his profile picture too.

Comment: it's not always but only*

Comment: i see, you can specify the token if used form._token if i recall well and the enctype inside the form one of those might have been the issue if form_widget(form) works